# Handling TreeView mouse double click

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview

How to handle TreeView double or right mouse click in WinProc?
i have tried this:

```
if(LOWORD(wParam) == GetWindowID(g_hWndTV &&
    HIWORD(wParam) == WM_RBUTTONUP)
......
```

but this does not work.
Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both these events will come via a `WM_NOTIFY` message sent to the tree control's parent window. You'll get [`NM_RCLICK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a right-click, and [`NM_DBLCLK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a double-click.

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    if (reinterpret_cast<LPNMHDR>(lParam)->hwndFrom == g_hWndTV)
    {
         if (reinterpret_cast<LPNMHDR>(lParam)->code == NM_RCLICK)
         {
              // right-click
         }
         else
         if (reinterpret_cast<LPNMHDR>(lParam)->code == NM_DBLCLK)
         {
              // double-click
         }
    }
    break;
```